# No module named 'fusioncharts'

Tags: python, django, database, django-views, fusioncharts

I am trying to plot fusion chart in django after adding fusioncharts,I am getting an error.

```
from fusioncharts import FusionCharts
FusionCharts ModuleNotFoundError:
```

Comment: did you install it?

Comment: I am trying but it's showing `pip install fusioncharts
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fusioncharts (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fusioncharts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you get such an error it is because you forgot to install the module, did a bit of research and came to the conclusion that you can install using pip: open the command prompt use the command `pip install twFusionCharts`.If this does not work, take a look at the [fusioncharts site](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/exporting-charts/using-fusionexport/sdk-api-reference/python), you will find there the indications for the alternative installation for all operating systems.